# Regex to extract all possible combinations of characters between group of keys

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling with a problem of regular expressions: I have a string like this:

```
number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678, and 9123 too...
```

What I want to do, is to get all possible groups of up to 50 characters between the word "number" and the four digits:

```
Group1: number I need is 1234

Group2: number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678

Group3: number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678, and 9123
```

I am trying with:

```
number.{0,50}\d{4}
```

which gives

```
number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678, and 9123
```

and also trying with:

```
number.{0,50}?\d{4}
```

which gets only:

```
number I need is 1234
```

I could solve this with a for loop, in which I delete the found text at each new iteraction, but I wonder if there's a unique regex to do that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please format you question so that it can be understood. Add the example string.

Comment: Hello, I put that already: number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678, and 9123 too...

Comment: How do you get `5678` from a string that is contains a literal `1234`?

Comment: Mu string contains both 1234 and 5678: I would like to extract both the substring from "number" to "1234" (I already do that) and also from "number" to "5678", like I stated in the original post. So, my result needs to be a group consisting in: number I need is 1234; and also a group consisting in:  number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678. I hope that now it's all clear.

Comment: Please put you actual example string and what you want to extract from it.

Comment: I wonder if you actually read my original post :D

Comment: Is this you string: `number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678, and 9123 too...`?

Comment: As I stated above, yes! I also explained what I want to extract from that. I hope that's clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the cleanest way is to use a loop that adds to the pattern:

```
import re 

s='number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678, and 9123 too...'


pat=r'(number.{0,50}?\d\d\d\d'
addition=r'.{0,50}?\d\d\d\d'
while m:=re.search(pat+')', s):
    print(m.group(1))
    pat+=addition
```

Prints:

```
number I need is 1234
number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678
number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678, and 9123
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I actually was thinking at the for loop, but I was also wondering if such a problem can be solved with a single regex.

Comment: The problem with a single regex is the match uses characters which defeats the next two matches. You might be able to cobble together something with lookahead but it would be a beast

Comment: Ok, thank you again for your help. Then for me it's enough

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using a single pattern to match all occurrences, and then loop the results of splitting on the position right after 4 digits.

```
number(?:.{0,50}?\d{4})+
```

- `number` Match literally
- `(?:` No capture group

  - `.{0,50}?\d{4}` Match any char 0-50 times non greedy, then match 4 digits
- `)+` Close the group and repeat 1+ times to match at least a single occurrence

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zXS57t/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yy3Kj5)

For example

```
import re

s = "number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678, and 9123 too..."
pattern = r"number(?:.{0,50}?\d{4})+"
res = ""
m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    for s in filter(None, re.split(r"(?<=\d{4})", m.group())):
        res += s
        print(res)
```

Output

```
number I need is 1234
number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678
number I need is 1234, but I also need 5678, and 9123
```

Comment: An elegant solution, I didn't know the pattern of split you used.